# Append to the end of a line in an Ant Build File

Tags: ant, build, ant-contrib

So i have an ant build file which needs to modify this other file named modify.properties. In this properties file i have a line such as this -

```
 CSDT_FLAG_CSELEMENT_FWUIDS=CSElement:4f826165-4744-4d78-63f0-4f437eb17872,b2db8c3d-ec81-4c6e-9425-ff0860f4511b,13f5a17a-8dac-443b-bcf8-b1675e660c53
```

In my build file I will search for the term CSElement and get the line that contains this term

```
  <loadfile
    property="csdtFlagPropertiesFile"
        srcFile="../cms-distribution/src/main/x/csdtflags.properties">
            <filterchain>
                <filterreader classname="org.apache.tools.ant.filters.LineContainsRegExp">
                        <param type="regexp" value="CSElement"/>                                                                            
                </filterreader>
            </filterchain>
    </loadfile>
```

Now i have the line  CSDT_FLAG_CSELEMENT_FWUIDS=CSElement:4f826165-4744-4d78-63f0-4f437eb17872,b2db8c3d-ec81-4c6e-9425-ff0860f4511b,13f5a17a-8dac-443b-bcf8-b1675e660c53 and i can replace the line using the containsregex method in filterchain however i am unable to write this back onto the file. A message such as echo message will rewrite the entire file but i just want to replace that line with another line. replacing works but this saves it into a property and i dont know how i can rewrite this on the file. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task to make a substitution in the file.